# When I am running npm run test in my Angular project, I get this RangeError:

Tags: karma-webpack

Chrome Headless 89.0.4389.114 (Windows 10) ERROR
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
at localhost/*karma_webpack*/node_modules/zone.js/dist/mocha-patch.js

I tried a lot of things, even adding include:false in files section from karma.conf.js but didn't work. Do you have any idea what can cause this issue?